# Clicking buttons in set order (ie. 1,2,3,4,5,...)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a similar game to Clickable mines 1-100 (found on Sporcle https://www.sporcle.com/games/RobPro/1-100-click-me). The game is straight forward, there are 100 buttons with a single number inside (1-100), you have to find the button with the text of 1, then 2, and so forth until you click on button 100.

I have a script that randomly prints buttons with the value from 1-20 and when clicked their background-color is changed to red. I want to associate a value with each button based on their text (button that displays 5 should have a value of 5). I want to keep count and make a function that only allows someone to click on a button only if it is the next button in order (you can only click button 4 if you have clicked on button 3, only click on button 3 if you have clicked on button 2, etc. How would I go about creating a function that only changes the buttons color if it is clicked in the correct order (button 10's color should not change if it's clicked before button 9)

```
var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"];
var n = array.length;
var tempArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {

    tempArr.push(array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1)[0]);
}

tempArr.push(array[0]);
array = tempArr;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    document.write("<button>" + array[i] + "</button>")
}



clicked = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        if (clicked) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            clicked = false;
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            clicked = true;
        }
    });
});
console.log();
```

Comment: Your are going to need to be more precise than "What do I do next" for us to be able to help you.

Comment: You could store the last clicked number in a variable, if the next click is bigger than one then you can reveal it.

Comment: Objective: Pick a button out of 100 buttons and if it's value is 1 then you can go on to find button value 2. If not then try another button until you get button value 1. Why would you force a user to pick the next button and no other button and why randomly generate 20 values when you need 100 values?

Comment: I am just using 20 for now until I get the game working and then I will add more.

Comment: I revised my post, I don't want to disable buttons, but I want to change their background color only if they are clicked in the correct order. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
    var prevButton = 0; //The button that was cilcked before: 0 if no button has been clicked yet
    var howManyButtons = 20; // How many buttons do you want

    // A function that is called when a button is clicked with a (this) sent to it
    // you can read more about (this) on internet
    function checkButton(clickedButton){

        // check if id of current button is one ahead of the prevButton such as 3 - 1 == 2
        if(Number(clickedButton.id) -1 == prevButton)
        {
            // If it is then change the background color of it to red
            clickedButton.style.background = "red";
            // Then make prevButton point to current button id
            prevButton++;
        }
    }

    // function to generate buttons
    function createButtons(){
        // Write a div tag to document with class name (game)
        document.write("<div class='game'>");
        // Loop to generate buttons
        for (var i = 1; i <= howManyButtons; i++){
            // write button tags to document with id=i when i = 1, 2, 3, 4, .. and call checkButton function when clicked and pass (this) to it
            document.write("<button id=" + i + " onclick='checkButton(this)'>" + i + "</button>");
        }
        // write closed div tag
        document.write("</div>");
    }

    // function that shuffles the buttons to a random position
    function shuffleButtons(){
        // get the div that buttons are in it
        var div = document.querySelector('.game');
        // Loop that start from our number of buttons 20 and goes to 0
        for (var i = howManyButtons; i >= 0; i--) {
            // append a button to the new random position 
            div.appendChild(div.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
        }
    }

    createButtons();
    shuffleButtons();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: *"Don't forget thumbs up."*: this really is an invitation to get downvoted. Don't put such things in your answer. Instead write some content that might get you an upvote, like an *explanation* of what was wrong and how you have corrected it, and why that works.

Comment: Good luck with your game.

Answer (score 0):

A good pattern to follow in software development is to separate your view rendering logic from your data, otherwise known as your model. Here you've got your buttons' state as your data, so you could store each button as its value and its state like:

```
var buttons = [
    {value: 1, state: 'pressed'},
    {value: 2, state: 'not_pressed'}
]
```

Then, you make a render function that replaces the html with the current state of your buttons. Each button would be bound to a click handler. You'll notice the click handler is initialized with a reference to the current button, like:

```
// Sudo code for rendering
function render() {
    buttonsContainer.empty();
    buttons.forEach(function(button) {
        var buttonHtml = renderButton(button);
        buttonHtml.on('click', function() {
            if (allowedToClickButton(button) {
                setButtonClicked(button);
            }
        });
        buttonsContainer.append(buttonHtml);
    }
}
```

Upgrading to a client side templating framework would be even better. Handlebars is good if you're not using anything else, or you could upgrade to React or Angular if you want a more comprehensive framework.